How to add static text paragraph to all the emails sent out of Salesforce?
GOAL: All emails sent out of Salesforce must have the static text paragraph which is a disclaimer basically like below:
Disclaimer: This email and any attachments are confidential and intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. If you are not the intended recipient, please notify the sender immediately and delete this email from your system. Any unauthorized review, use, disclosure, or distribution is prohibited. Please note that the views or opinions presented in this email are solely those of the author and do not necessarily represent those of the organization. While this email has been scanned for viruses, the recipient should check for the presence of viruses, as the sender accepts no liability for any damage caused by any virus transmitted by this email.
ACCEPTANCE CRITERIA:

It should be sent to people outside my company so their email address will not have my company's email domain.
The sender cannot edit it or delete it.
The receiver cannot edit it or delete it if they are forwarding to any one.

THINGS TRIED SO FAR:
I created email footer with the above static disclaimer as a result now every email sent outside has this disclaimer text. I tested by sending mail through "Send mail" button in Activity component on Contact object, sent a mail through scheduled flow and sent an email through apex code to test by various ways. However the requirement was that only for people outside it should have been sent or appended to the email. And foremost I can still edit and modify it and receiver also can do that.
Please can one guide me to the right path even if I have to do customization using Apex.

Hi, thanks for your question and the detail included. Typically organisations that have these kind of requirements would be using Email Relay and actually relying on existing mail servers to meet this requirement, or at least that has been my experience. If you're using Email Relay, have you talked to whoever manages the mail servers to see if they can help?
